# Display texte or unicode in column

Tags: t-sql, unicode

I have two columns in my table, one contains latin caracteres (varchar) and another contains unicodes (n'varchar).

What I want is when my first column is null then display the second column :

```
isnull(column_1, column_2)
```

This doesn't work. So I tried to convert the select to n'varchar like this

```
convert(n'varchar(50),isnull(column_1, column_2))
```

But it doesn't work aswell. The unicode value is displayed with question marks '?'.

So have you an idea how to display the text or unicode (when text is null take the unicode)?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert the column inside:

```
select isnull(cast(column_1 as nvarchar(50)), column_2) from table
```

Your query convert the Unicode text to non-unicode (at this point the invalid data is converted to `?` and practically lost) and then convert it back to Unicode (but it is too late, because the data is already lost).

Answer (score 0):

[`IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns a value with the same data type as the first argument, in this case `VarChar(n)`. The second argument, an `NVarChar(n)`, is therefore converted to a `VarChar(n)`. (More precisely: "Returns the same type as *check_expression*. If a literal NULL is provided as *check_expression*, returns the datatype of the *replacement_value*. If a literal NULL is provided as *check_expression* and no *replacement_value* is provided, returns an `int`.")

[`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns a value with the highest data type precedence from its arguments. According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) an `NVarChar` is higher than a `VarChar` and the implicit conversion will occur the way you want.

`Coalesce` can accept more than two arguments, is ISO/ANSI SQL, and respects data type precedence.